# Angular 2 CLI variables don't get updated

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, angular-cli

First of all, I'm totally new to Angular 2 and yesterday I tried using the Angular CLI for my first project ever, and failed. The Angular CLI seems to not be working for me - what I mean, the variables are not getting updated in my views.

I did the standard procedure here:

- ng new projectname
- cd projectname
- npm start

The server at *localhost:4200* starts and then I tried adding a new element - a paragraph - to the /src/app/app.component.html template:

```
    <p>This text gets displayed</p>
```

The CLI informed me that everything is fine and the browser refreshed automatically, and then I saw the default "app works!" heading and my new paragraph with text inside.

But then, I decided to change the *title* variable in **app.component.ts** file, so my new class declaration looked like this:

```
    export class AppComponent {
        title = 'New App Title!';
    }
```

The CLI again told me that everything is fine, but no changes were seen in the browser. I refreshed the page manually, but no changes were present - the heading still said "app works!".

So I tried adding a new variable to the file:

```
   otherText = "some other text";
```

Then added another paragraph to my template:

```
   <p>New text: {{otherText}}</p>
```

The paragraph got shown on the webpage, but the *{{otherText}}* variable contents were missing. The page looked like this:

```
    <h1>app works!</h1>
    <p>this text gets displayed</p>
    <p>New text: </p>
```

Does anyone know what might be the problem here? What can I do to make the variables work? I don't have this kind of problem when I work with the [standard quickstart package](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/quickstart.html), only with the CLI.

I'm on a Windows 10 machine, I tried updating Node.js and NPM but that didn't help.

**@edit:** The variables actually get updated, but I have to start the server with `ng serve`, and I have to kill it and re-start it every time I make a change to a variable to see the changes.

Comment: Did you try close/reopen browser?

Answer (score 2):

This is currently a known issue in the CLI which started yesterday, you can track the status of it [here](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/4338)

Answer (score 0):

`@angular/cli@1.0.0` has an error for live-reload.

Downgrade to `@angular/cli@1.0.0-rc.4`. 
Then `rm -rf node_modeules`. Reinstall all of the dependencies.